# Cannot find the declaration of the element 'diops'

Tags: java, xml, xsd

i'm new on this XML stuff, and i'm having one issue with the location of the element diops.

Here is my xml

```
<diops 
    xmlns:ans="ttp://dados.wsh.com.br/diopsxml-2016/xsd/2016/xsd/2016" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:SchemaLocation="http://dados.wsh.com.br/diopsxml-2016/xsd/2016 Diops2016.xsd">
```

And here is my XSD

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.ans.gov.br/ws/diops/financeiro/schema/v2016" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.ans.gov.br/ws/diops/financeiro/schema/v2016" 
    version="1.1">

    <xs:include schemaLocation="DiopsComplexTypes2016.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="diops">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="tns:identificacao"/>
                <xs:element name="financeiro" type="tns:financeiro"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The message that appear to me is: "Cannot find the declaration of the element 'diops'.

But he is the first element that i declare in the XSD file, with the other elements i dont have any issue, only with the element called 'diops'.

Sorry about my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to validate yout XML document against the schema.

Anyways, your schema defines the `<diops>` element to be in the `http://www.ans.gov.br/ws/diops/financeiro/schema/v2016` namespace (that's what the *targetNamespace* attribute does). However, in your XML document, the `<diops>` element belongs to the *empty* namespace.

You should simply add a namespace declaration in your XML document:

```
<diops xmlns="http://www.ans.gov.br/ws/diops/financeiro/schema/v2016"  ... >
```

Comment: The OP should probably also spell the name of the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute correctly (lowercase 's').